# Best way to get request object from within Symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony1

I use Symfony and Doctrine to generate forms for my CMSes. Lately I've been customizing them by setting default values based on specific URL parameters.

For example, I have two models: `PollQuestion` and `PollChoice`. `PollChoice` has a relation to `PollQuestion` by means of a `poll_question_id` field. The `PollChoice` form has a dropdown that lists all the available `PollQuestion`s that the `PollChoice` can be attached to.  I also have two routes: `pollchoices/new` and `poll/:poll_id/choice/new`. Both routes display the `PollChoiceForm`, but by using the 2nd route you would automatically see the PollQuestion dropdown set to the `:poll_id` URL parameter. I do this by simply changing the default value of the dropdown widget in the `PollChoiceForm` class by fetching the value of `:poll_id` from the request object.

My question is two-fold:

1) I currently fetch the request object by using `sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()`. I know that `sfContext::getInstance()` is frowned upon, but I haven't been able to find another way to fetch it. Is there another way? Dependency injection seems like a good way to go, but I don't know how to accomplish that without doing a lot of hacking (which I'd like to avoid).

2) Am I completely going about the wrong way of changing a form's default values based on URL parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I need the context in a form, I'm doing it via constructor injection.

in the action:

```
$this->form = new WhateverForm($whatever, array("context" => $this->getContext()));
```

in the form:

```
$this->getOption("context");
```

Comment: I like this method. I think I would edit my custom admin theme's actions to automatically inject it within the constructor.