# Accessing sfWebRequest in Symfony Form Class?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I Currently writing a form for user to create a new record that require user's IP address.

I have this ready: `$this->getObject()->setIp(ip2long($sf_request->getRequest()->getHttpHeader ('addr','remote')));`

But it is obvious that I do not have the $sf_request object in my Form model. How can I access to this and get the user's IP address?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345437/best-way-to-get-request-object-from-within-symfony-forms

Comment: Not a dupplicate. I found a solution and posted the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Access to the $request parameter of the Action method and extract the ip from the http headers. Then, in the view file, try to send the variable as parameter to the form file. I don't know exactly how, but i know for example you can pass an object as a parameter to the form to fill it

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After a moment think about this. I move the setIP method to my action and override the default processForm method with this:

```
  public function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form){
    $form->getObject()->setIp(ip2long($request->getHttpHeader ('addr','remote')));
    return parent::processForm($request, $form);
  }
```

It works just fine.

Comment: Another (and better) way is to add a "request" option on your form. And I understand that you are using symfony Admin Generator. So you can use the moduleGeneratorConfiguration->getFormOptions() method !

This way you can inject any dependency to the Form.