# How to save with form GET attribute?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I generated simply model with Symfony.

```
Job:
  columns:
    from_get:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    type:         { type: string(255) }
```

in JobForm.class.php:

```
$this->setWidget('from_get', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
```

and i have action:

http://mysite.com/job/new?get=3

How can i save id=3 to from_get automatically?

in JobForm.class.php

```
$this->setDefault('from_get', $this->request->getParemeter('get'));
```

doesnt working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best place to access the request object is your module/action.

```
//in your module job
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->form = new JobForm();
  $this->form->setDefault('from_get', $request->getParameter('get'));

  //... your code
}
```

By the way, you can pass the context to the form via constructor injection. Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345437/best-way-to-get-request-object-from-within-symfony-forms) to see a possible implementation.